# Flink temporal join works only for a few seconds

Tags: join, apache-flink, debezium, flink-sql

I'm trying to implement an event time temporal join in Flink. Here's the first join table:

```
   tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka (" +
            "`timestamp` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3)," +
            "`area` STRING," +
            "`networkEdge` STRING," +
            "`vehiclesNumber` BIGINT," +
            "`averageSpeed` INTEGER," +
            "WATERMARK FOR `timestamp` AS `timestamp`" +
            ") WITH (" +
            "'connector' = 'kafka'," +
            "'topic' = 'seneca.trafficdata.aggregated'," +
            "'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092'," +
            "'properties.group.id' = 'traffic-data-aggregation-job'," +
            "'format' = 'json'," +
            "'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'" +
            ")");
```

The table is used as a sink for the following query:

```
   Table aggregatedTrafficData = trafficData
            .window(Slide.over(lit(30).seconds())
                    .every(lit(15).seconds())
                    .on($("timestamp"))
                    .as("w"))
            .groupBy($("w"), $("networkEdge"), $("area"))
            .select(
                    $("w").end().as("timestamp"),
                    $("area"),
                    $("networkEdge"),
                    $("plate").count().as("vehiclesNumber"),
                    $("speed").avg().as("averageSpeed")
            );
```

Here's the other join table. I use Debezium to stream a Postgres table into Kafka:

```
    tEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka (" +
            "`timestamp` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL," +
            "`urn` STRING," +
            "`flow_rate` INTEGER," +
            "PRIMARY KEY(`urn`) NOT ENFORCED," +
            "WATERMARK FOR `timestamp` AS `timestamp`" +
            ") WITH (" +
            "'connector' = 'kafka'," +
            "'topic' = 'seneca.network.transport_network_edge'," +
            "'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset'," +
            "'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092'," +
            "'properties.group.id' = 'traffic-data-aggregation-job'," +
            "'format' = 'debezium-json'," +
            "'debezium-json.schema-include' = 'true'" +
            ")");
```

Finally here's the temporal join:

```
    Table transportNetworkCongestion = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka.`timestamp`, `networkEdge`, " +
            "congestion(`vehiclesNumber`, `flow_rate`) AS `congestion` FROM AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka " +
            "JOIN TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka.`timestamp` " +
            "ON AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka.`networkEdge` = TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka.`urn`");
```

The problem I'm having is that the join works only for the first few second (after an update in the Postgres table), but I need to continuosly join the first table with debezium one. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks
euks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporal joins using the AS OF syntax you're using require:

- an append-only table with a valid event-time attribute
- an updating table with a primary key and a valid event-time attribute
- an equality predicate on the primary key

When Flink SQL's temporal operators are applied to event time streams, watermarks play a critical role in determining when results are produced, and when the state is cleared.

When performing a temporal join:

- rows from the append-only table are buffered in Flink state until the current watermark of the join operator reaches their timestamps
- for the versioned table, for each key the latest version whose timestamp precedes the join operator's current watermark is kept in state, plus any versions from after the current watermark
- whenever the join operator's watermark advances, new results are produced, and state that's no longer relevant is cleared

The join operator tracks the watermarks it receives from its input channels, and its current watermark is always the minimum of these two watermarks. This is why your join stalls, and only makes progress when the flow_rate is updated.

One way to fix this would be to set the watermark for the TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka table with something like this:

```sql
WATERMARK FOR timestamp as CAST('9999-12-31 00:00:00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))
```

This will set the watermark for this table/stream to a very large value, which will have the effect of making the watermarks from this stream irrelevant -- this stream's watermarks will never be the smallest.

This will, however, have the drawback of making the join results non-deterministic.

Comment: The sliding window query "feeds" the AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka table used in the temporal join. What do you mean with the stream has become idle? AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka emits data every 15 seconds but the TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka emits data only when there's an update in the "flow_rate" parameter (which occurs vary rarely).

Comment: In practice what happens is AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka emits data every 15 seconds. The temporal join works for a few seconds then stops. If I update the flow_rate parameter in Postgres (so the TransportNetworkEdge_Kafka updates) the join resumes to work for the previous emitted AggregatedTrafficData_Kafka events and for a few seconds then it stops again. In practice I have to update the Postgres table periodically to make it work but I want the join to work even without the table update.

Comment: Now I understand what's going on, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the largest watermark value and now it works continuosly as I was expecting.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work as is, but rather with: `"WATERMARK FOR timestamp as CAST('9999-12-31 00:00:00.000' as TIMESTAMP(3))"`.  Perhaps the newer versions of flink (I'm using 1.16) convert watermarks to string differently.

Comment: @MikeGM Thanks. My answer would only work with the Table API, and not in the SQL Client, so I've updated my answer to use your approach.

Comment: One more comment: this is essentially a workaround to get "processing time" joins (which will hopefully be addressed here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-326:+Enhance+Watermark+to+Support+Processing-Time+Temporal+Join?show-miniview). We have used this technique to enrich using a CDC build side table, but it's important to note that this *will* stall again in the case of a restart/reboot from checkpoint *until* a new record is written in the build side. One can workaround this by injecting a record on reboot or if a restart occurs.